# RpDesignerVCL to spanish (reportmanager)

Tags: delphi, reportmanager

How can I change the language of RpDesignerVCL to spanish, i have a delphi apllication and when I execute the RpDesignerVCL component it appears i enlgelish.
Thanks
Alejandro Jourdan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo have to put "reportmanres.es" in the application directory